# Can't configure the HighVoltage gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, high-voltage

I'm using [High Voltage](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage) for static pages in a Rails 4 app. I'd like to specify a static home page [as outlined here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage#specifying-a-root-path) but I get the following error on server bootup:

```
undefined method `configure' for HighVoltage:Module (NoMethodError)
```

I have a high_voltage.rb file in config/initializers so can't understand what's going wrong here. High Voltage works fine besides this.

UPDATE:

Gemfile has the following line:

```
gem 'high_voltage'
```

Gemfile.lock:

```
high_voltage (2.0.0)
```

high_voltage.rb:

```
HighVoltage.configure do |config|
  config.home_page = 'home'
end
```

Comment: how did you include the gem into **Gemfile**?

Comment: What do you mean by 'works fine besides this'? Also could you mention the version high_voltage in Gemfile.lock

Comment: As above, please include the high_voltage declaration from your Gemfile as well as the contents of the initializer file you have created, even if you have just taken them from the github README.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at the codebase of version 2.0 here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage/tree/11e38c643ff8b5ea1c6e04999034a8d5bcb4f711

There is no such version implemented in the gem.

It was added just recently: https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage/commit/1668e54be41dd50f6c36ac6ab6d46069ffd0d636

Comment: In other words, just type: bundle update high_voltage